# Создание экземпляра класса внутри другого класса Python

Tags: python, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть такой код. Когда препод увидел, что создаю экземпляры класса прям в init, то сказал, что так не хорошо делать. Посоветовал почитать по паттерны. Немного почитал и увидел, что в этом нет ничего плохого. Возможно стоит вынести создание экземпляров в отдельный метод?

```
class Train:
    def __init__(self, route, timetable):
        self._route = route
        self._timetable = timetable
        self._station_now = None
        self._status = None  # None, На станции, В пути, Сломан

        self._train_delay = TrainDelay(5, 0.1, 10, 30)
        self._train_breakdown = TrainBreakdown(60, 0.001, 120, 180)
        self._train_stop = None
```

Comment: Я тут вижу проблему не в создании объектов внутри `__init__` как таковом, а в том, что параметры этих объектов прописаны жестко, и вы никак на них не повлияете кроме как модификацией кода самого класса. Поэтому лучше или параметры передавать снаружи, или сами объекты создавать снаружи, и передавать в Train при его создании.

Comment: если создоваемые классы `train...` являются потомками\родителями основного класса, то да это дичь, есть специальные методы реализации функции инит родительского класса, а если классы дочерние то ваще треш, и нужен абстрактный класс, являющийся конечным потомком

Comment: За 6 лет работы я первый раз слышу, чтобы само по себе создание экземпляров другого класса в init считалось чем-то неправильным. Либо ваш препод сам плохо разбирается в общепринятых практиках программирования, либо вы его неправильно поняли.